# Can I use the term "project platform"?

Tags: translation

I'm currently creating a web application for specialized projects.

They can be added, edited, graded, published in a database etc. We were looking for a name for this app and thought that "Project Platform" would fit.

Now I have some doubts because we came up with it from its German version "Projekt-Plattform". I'm not sure if the word "platform" can be used in this meaning in English.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a pretty standard usage in English.  Your project platform is what space you're targeting your project to work in, while your development platform is what you use to make said application.

For example:

If you're developing for Android, Android is your project platform and Java/the Android SDK is your development platform.

Comment: Thanks, Jacob. I'm aware of the use Platform for talking about operating systems, IDEs etc.. But what I'm doing is none of such but just an application to manage certain aspects of a project. In this case, does the term "platform" apply, too?

Comment: @lorenz: Do you mean something like, Doxygen for documentation or Microsoft OneNote to keep the team on track?

In that case I wouldn't call it a platform, but rather a part of your projects "toolchain" or just a tool.